# i want to give filepath out of the webroot in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

i want to give file path out of the webroot, how to give it?

```
$uploads_dir =  WWW_ROOT .'/uploads';


                    $tmp_name = $this->data["Image"]["filedata"]["tmp_name"];
                    $name = $this->data["Image"]["filedata"]["name"];
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
```

Comment: `WWW_ROOT` holds the full path to the webroot. What do you mean by "file path out of the webroot"? Do you want the directory which holds the `webroot` directory? In that case, use `APP`.

Comment: basically i want to save images out of the webroot folder in cakephp, not in the webroot folder of cake php, i didn't how to give it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another constant. Cake has a few globally defined constants you can use, see [the documentation here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#core-definition-constants).

In you case you want to save images in a directory outside the webroot directory (not sure if that's wise, though), so you should use `APP` instead of `WWW_ROOT` as the former holds the path to the directory you're application is in.

Comment: kindly tell me one thing more, if i want to save it in my computer, then what i do?

Comment: That's a rather broad question and might merit it's own question. In theory a PHP script will be able to save a file to any location on the hard drive as long as that location is writable by the webserver.

Comment: how can i do it in cakephp? any suggestion?

Comment: As Cake is just a layer of convenience (and abstraction) on top of core PHP the implementation would be roughly the same as in PHP. Cake does offer some convenience methods when working with files and directories (see the manual: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html), but for more advanced usage you would need a plugin or component.